# Derivative of products of two functions

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a function $V$ which is a product of two functions:
$$V = λ(x_1^α+x_2^α).$$
How would I be able to differentiate it with respect to $λ$ and $α$, i.e.,
$$\frac{∂V}{∂λ},\ \frac{∂V}{∂α}?$$
Thanks.

Comment: The same way you do like any other partial derivative: hold one variable fixed and allow the other to vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy. $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial\lambda}=x_1^\alpha+x_2^\alpha$$ and $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial\alpha}=\lambda(x_1^\alpha \ln x_1+x_2^\alpha \ln x_2)$$